# How to display results from Stored Procedure WinForms

Tags: sql-server, winforms, stored-procedures, ado.net

I have a stored procedure in SQL Server that returns different structures based on the parameters.

In other words, it might return a result set with three fields, or 15, and the column names are going to be different.

How can I display these results in a WinForm app?

I currently use the Entity Framework for accessing data, but obviously that is not going to work in this situation.

The data will be readonly, ie, no need to edit.  Just need to display it.

I am guessing that I need to skip EF and just call the SP directly, and populate a DataGridView with autocolumns.

Greg

Comment: That's a horrible database design - the structure of a result set for a given stored procedure ought to be **stable** and **fixed**. Having it change its shape depending on the input parameters makes it really really REALLY hard to use this procedure.... I'd fix this design flaw before anything else....

Comment: If you have a SP there is no real need to use EF, just use ADO.NET ([SqlCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.aspx) and its like) and call the stored procedure directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the best answer I found: [How to use a DataAdapter with stored procedure and parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3528305/how-to-use-a-dataadapter-with-stored-procedure-and-parameter)

In short, use a DataAdapter and a DataTable.  Even with AutoGenerateColumns, the column headers look great and it works no matter the table structure that comes back.

Greg

Answer (score 0):

Since you're retrieving a dynamic data structure you'll need to make your grid columns dynamic too. What I would do is, after retrieving the result set successfully, to clear the `Columns` collection and recreate them from scratch every time you called the SP and the data needs to be refreshed on-screen. Do not use `AutoGenerateColumns`, as they provide little chance to customize the look of them, instead define each and every column yourself so that you can choose what to display and how.

Comment: In this case, I am at the mercy of the writer of the stored procedure, so I can't know in advance what data is coming back, thus I can't create the columns in advance.  In any case, the accepted answer shows a good solution to this.

Comment: Don't seem like a good alternative (even though it works for sure), because it leaves out any chance to optimize the visual appearance of the final data for the user. Auto generation will always work, but problem is that you can't do any formating, alignment, readable headers or any eye-candy you may want. Even if you don't control the SP at all, at least I think you should be informed about its results for each parameter combination, so you can layout your UI accordingly for your end users, as they no doubt don't like raw DB data.