# WPF MS SQL Stored Procedure times out

Tags: c#, sql, wpf

My application needs to get data from a store procedure.  In a query program the stored procedure works fine;

```
exec MyStoredProdure @Prama1 = '01'
```

In WPF it times out.  Here is my code;

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConString))
{
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Prama1", "01");
    cmd.CommandText = "MyStoredProdure";
    cmd.Connection = con;
    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable("MyStoredProdure");
    sda.Fill(dt);

    foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
    {
       //Do code
    }
    con.Close();
}
```

It is timing out right on `sda.Fill(dt)`.  It should be noted that Select and inserts work perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you're missing the sda.SelectCommand = cmd; before the fill.
[How to use a DataAdapter with stored procedure and parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3528305/how-to-use-a-dataadapter-with-stored-procedure-and-parameter)