# Stored procedure for lang

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to get data for selected langugage but this query gets all data...

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_GetAbout]
AS
    SELECT 
        About.[AboutID],
        Languages.Name as LangCode,
        [About].[AboutUs], [About].[AboutUs], 
        [About].[Mission], [About].[Vision], [About].[AboutPhoto],
        CASE 
           WHEN About.IsActive = 'True' 
              THEN 'Active' 
              ELSE 'Passive'
        END AS Statu
    FROM 
        [dbo].[About]
    INNER JOIN 
        Languages on About.LangCode = Languages.Code
    WHERE
        About.Statu = 'True' 
    ORDER BY
        Statu, Languages.Name
```

Comment: So you only want the data from the 'About' table?

Comment: @sr28 he wants to filter by `LangCode`. Most likely passing the language code via a parameter to the stored procedure and then adjusting the `WHERE` clause

Comment: in about table i have 2 langugaes data. my web multilanguage so when i selected english, it should have to get only english data. but i think this query is not true?

Comment: @Shqiptar you need to filter by `LangCode`, so look at adding a parameter to your stored procedure so that when you call it, you can specify the language code as mentioned earlier.

Comment: yes im trying `About.AboutID = About.LangCode`  but it was error.. pls help me.

Comment: @Shqiptar - the point of adding the parameter is to allow you to filter as per your request. That means at the point of calling the stored procedure you actually need to supply something for that parameter. If you don't, which you're currently not, you will get an error saying as much. So presumably in your c# code somewhere you are calling this. You now need to alter that to supply a value for your new parameter.

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: Hi Shqiptar; if you have extra information to add, for example in response to a comment, you are encouraged to [edit] your question to include the new information; that makes it easiest to read, and most useful to other users of the site.

Answer (score 0):

You should pass input parameter for Language name. For example

```
ALTER Proc [dbo].[sp_GetAbout]
   @LangName nvarchar(3) 
    as
    SELECT About.[AboutID],

         Languages.Name as LangCode

          ,[About].[AboutUs],[About].[AboutUs],[About].[Mission],[About].[Vision],[About].[AboutPhoto],


          case when About.IsActive='True' then 'Active' else 'Passive'end as Statu


      FROM [dbo].[About]
      INNER JOIN Languages on About.LangCode = Languages.Code
      Where About.Statu='True' and LangCode = @LangName Order by Statu,Languages.Name
```

Then call using

```
EXEC [dbo].[sp_GetAbout] @LangName = 'ENG'
```

Also note to change the parameter type for your case. Because You didn't provided how you store languages.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add parameter to your procedure.

```
ALTER Proc [dbo].[sp_GetAbout] @Lang nvarchar(30) AS
SELECT About.[AboutID],
       Languages.Name AS LangCode ,
       [About].[AboutUs],
       [About].[AboutUs],
       [About].[Mission],
       [About].[Vision],
       [About].[AboutPhoto],
       CASE
           WHEN About.IsActive='True' THEN 'Active'
           ELSE 'Passive'
       END AS Statu
FROM [dbo].[About]
INNER JOIN Languages ON About.LangCode = Languages.Code
WHERE About.Statu='True'
  AND LangCode = @Lang
ORDER BY Statu,
         Languages.Name
```

Then you should call for it like

```
EXEC [dbo].[sp_GetAbout] @Lang = 'en-GB'
```

And for your C# function it's

```
public static DataTable GetAbout()
        {
            Fonksiyon f = new Fonksiyon();
            SqlConnection mycon = f.Baglanti;
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("sp_GetAbout", mycon);
            da.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@Lang", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = "en-GB";
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);
            da.Dispose();
            KayitSayisi = dt.Rows.Count;
            return dt;
        }
```

Comment: Error: `Procedure or function 'sp_GetAbout' expects parameter '@Lang', which was not supplied.`

Comment: cmon, you should pass parameter as error message says. added example to answer

Comment: because you are trying to to execute the procedure without passing a parameter value.

Comment: add it after da.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;  da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@Lang", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "English";

Comment: @Shqiptar just add the parameter to your command as shown above

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3528305/how-to-use-a-dataadapter-with-stored-procedure-and-parameter second answer