# Using an SqlDataAdapter with a stored procedure and parameters to update as well as retrieve values

Tags: c#, sql, stored-procedures, sqldataadapter

In [How to use a DataAdapter with stored procedure and parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3528305/how-to-use-a-dataadapter-with-stored-procedure-and-parameter), the data adapter's `selectCommand` property has been used. Can the same be used if a stored procedure updates as well as retrieves data from a database?

Answer (score 0):

On implementing it, and using the selectCommand (and not the  property, it seems to work alright.

```
...

        SqlDataAdapter sqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlQuery, sqlConnection);

        foreach (SqlParameter sqlParameter in sqlParameterCollection)
        {
            sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter(sqlParameter.ParameterName, sqlParameter.Value));
        }
        sqlDataAdapter.SelectCommand = sqlCommand;
        DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
        sqlDataAdapter.Fill(dataSet);
```

...

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is yes. Passing parameters to a stored procedure which updates and returns values is no different from the SqlDataAdapter side compared to a stored procedure that only returns values based on parameters passed in.